# PowerPivot how to remove column filter through VBA code

Tags: excel, powerpivot, vba

I have PowerPivot table that one of my macros had filter on column.
When I tried to create another Macro that clear the filter from it nothing happened.
I used the next two codes:

```
Private Sub Com3_click()
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[HVC_Sample].[Updated_task_status].[Updated_task_status]").VisibleItemsList = _
        Array("")
End Sub
```

And:

```
Private Sub Com2_Click()

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[HVC_Sample].[Updated_task_status].[Updated_task_status]").VisibleItemsList = _
        Array("[HVC_Sample].[Updated_task_status].&[Completed]")
End Sub
```

Both of them did not remove it, in addition if I manually do it filter is removed.
Any idea how to fix the code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under presumption, that you are selecting your table correctly:

```
Private Sub remove_filter()

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        .ClearAllFilters
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Avi22 Code works on my side, so it means the pivot table is not correctly selected.

Change `ActiveSheet` to `Sheets("<Sheetname where your pivot table is>")` and make sure your pivot table is really called "`PivotTable1`", if not then change it in selector.

Also, keep in mind, the procedure i provided is in it's own private sub, are you sure you didn't copy my code, and are calling procedure `com3_click()` while in the meantime my procedure is stored in `remove_filter()` (so in other words, it doesn't get called at all) ?

Comment: @Avi22 For clarity sake. Copy the entire code I provided, and then inside your `com3_Click()` code add the following line: 

`Call remove_filter`

Comment: I tried and I got same results... even I record macro and than re run it it failed to remove the filter...strange.

Comment: found the issue... I had "comm3" instead of "com3"
thanks it works great now!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ClearAllFilters` method:

```
Private Sub Com3_click()
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[HVC_Sample].[Updated_task_status].[Updated_task_status]").ClearAllFilters
End Sub
```